# SonarQube does not use Jacoco Reports if Unit-Tests fail

Tags: android, gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

I configured sonarQube and Jacoco to see the test coverage of my code. I'm testing an android app using gradle and Java.
If a Unit-Test fails the command `gradlew test` outputs the following:

```
> Task :app:testDebugUnitTest

[...].ConnectionTest > [...] FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError at ConnectionTest.java:21

1 test completed, 1 failed

> Task :app:testDebugUnitTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:testDebugUnitTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: [...]

BUILD FAILED in 5s
25 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 23 up-to-date
```

This is the expected behaviour I guess, but if I want to combine this with sonarQube using the following command, then sonarQube only uses the Jacoco report if all tests pass.

```
gradlew clean testDebugUnitTest sonarqube
```

This is the sonarQube.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9000/"
        property "sonar.projectKey", "android-sample-app"
        property "sonar.projectName", "android-sample-app"
        property "sonar.login", "[...]"
        property "sonar.tests", "src/test/java"
        property "sonar.test.inclusions", "**/*Test*/**"
        property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
        property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java"
        property "sonar.exclusions", '**/*Test*/**,' +
                'build/**' +
                '*.json,' +
                '**/*test*/**,' +
                '**/.gradle/**,' +
                '**/R.class'
        property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
        property "sonar.junit.reportPaths", "**/test-results/**/*.xml"
        property "sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths", "**/jacocoTestReport/jacocoTestReport.xml"
        property "sonar.coverage.exclusions", "${coverageExclusions.join(', ')}"
    }
}
```

This is my jacoco.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

ext {
    coverageExclusions = [
            '**/*Activity*.*',
            '**/*Fragment*.*',
            '**/R.class',
            '**/R$*.class',
            '**/BuildConfig.*',
    ]
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = '0.8.6'
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/reports")
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
    // https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/5184#issuecomment-457865951
    jacoco.excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']
}


tasks.withType(Test) {
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport // report is always generated after tests run
}

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest']) {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports for Debug build"

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/javac/debug/classes", excludes: coverageExclusions)
    def mainSrc = "/src/main/java"

    additionalSourceDirs.from = files(mainSrc)
    sourceDirectories.from = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories.from = files([debugTree])

    executionData.from = files("$buildDir/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec")
}
```

How can I setup sonarQube to work if Unit-Tests fail?

Comment: I can't solve your problem, but I would say that there's a good reason why most build systems don't try to do what you want to do.  If your unit tests are failing, you have bigger problems than code coverage.

Comment: But if you'd want to devlop in a test driven style, then you could not analyze your code using sonarQube until all tests are fullfilled, right?

Comment: "Developing in a test-driven style" refers to test-driven development, which is entirely driven by the success or failure of your tests.